# Perform Join on Two Collections on ID basis in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, join, go

I have two collections: ratings and bookings.

In bookings collection I have a field "_id" which is normal document id. I am also saving a field "location_id" in bookings collection. In ratings collection I am referencing id of the booking as "booking_id" field.

**Query1:**

I want to get count of ratings on the basis of "location_id" which means first I need to get bookings on the basis of location_id, then I need to find the ratings for that bookings (that has location with "location_id").

For this I have performed MongoDB join by aggregating two collections like this:

```
    getCollection := mongoSession.DB(config.Database).C(config.RatingsCollection)
    pipe := getCollection.Pipe([]bson.M{ 
                                        bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"location_id": 2}},
                                        bson.M{"$lookup": bson.M{
                                                            "localField"    : "booking_id",
                                                            "from"          : config.BookingsCollection,
                                                            "foreignField"  : "_id"}},
                                        bson.M{"$count": "ratings_count"}, })
    err = pipe.All(&result)
```

**Query2:**

Also I need to know how can we add more conditions (which are to be applied within the same collection) to our query ??

I need to perform this join operation query as well as some other conditions like in ratings collection I have another field like "rating_date" which contains the timestamp value.

```
condition :=  bson.M{}
condition["review_date"] = bson.M{"$gte": startDate, "$lte": endDate} 
allratingsCount, err := models.GetRatingsCount(condition)

func GetRatingsCount(query interface{}) (int, error){
    count, err := GetRecordsCount(config.RatingsCollection, query)
    if err != nil{
        return 0, err
    }
    return count, err
}
```

Like In code, I need to send another conditions with join query. Can I perform these two things together ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to add another `$match` stage to the pipeline?

Comment: You can say that. But do I need to match the another conditions within the same join query ? Isn't there any way to separately manage that conditions (apart from join) ?

Comment: So do you "*need to send another conditions with join query*" and "*perform these two things together*" or not?

Comment: yes I want these two things together. But I am asking Do I need to add another match stage as u said ? Or Is there another way to perform the queries together ?

Comment: Ah, I see, so you still need 2 numbers in the result returned by a single query, don't you? If so, it is quite an unusual requirement. Why do you need it?

Comment: No, I want a single count by performing all queries. I want a common rating count in which I can apply a join to match rating's "booking_id" with booking's "_id" on the basis of "location_id" and a condition to get ratings for a particular time period.

Comment: So it is an extra `$match`, I don't really get your comment about "*separately managed conditions*". If you need to count documents that match several filters, either add an extra `$match` stage or combine it with the existing one.

Comment: Okay let me know your answer with all filters within one join operation

Comment: Mind trying it yourself first? It should be fairly straightforward, but if there any problems with that, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155321/discussion-between-amandeep-kaur-and-alex-blex).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. Here is the complex JOIN operatin on two different collection to get the single count of Ratings:

```
getCollection := mongoSession.DB("example_db").C("ratings")
    pipe := getCollection.Pipe([]bson.M{ 
                                        bson.M{"$lookup": bson.M{
                                                            "localField"    : "booking_id",
                                                            "from"          : "bookings",
                                                            "foreignField"  : "_id",
                                                            "as"            : "data" }},
                                        bson.M{"$unwind": "$data"},
                                        bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"location_id": 1, "industry_id": 2, "proivder_id": 10, "rating": 4.5, "rating_date": bson.M{ "$gte": startDate, "$lte": endDate}}},
                                        bson.M{"$group": bson.M{
                                                            "_id": "null", 
                                                            "count": bson.M{"$sum": 1} } } } )
    err = pipe.One(&result)
```

In this way I get the count of ratings by joining two collections together along with different queries.